# how to disable a image button that acts as submit button

Tags: php, javascript

I have a image button thats acts as a form submit button:

```
<a href="#" onClick="submitComment('+[id]+'); return false;"><img class="submitcommentimg" id="submitcommentimg<?php echo $id; ?>" src="/images/check.png" alt="Comment!" border="0"></a>
```

What is the best way to 'disable' it to prevent accidental double clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the onclick handler on the anchor upon clicking on it.

Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="/* .. do all your things ... */ this.onclick = function(){}; return false;">
```

Comment: example written. notice the `this.onclick = function(){};` it removes the current onclick function that is binded.

Comment: @Neil - yep that's correct! Pardon me, because I work with jQuery frequently, typing `function(){}` is rather common for me.

Comment: Both those work.. But... Jump the page to the top... How can I prevent that.

Comment: jumping the page to the top is disabled by returning false.

Answer (score 1):

Change your onclick attribute to something like this:

```
onclick="submitComment('+[id]+'); this.onclick='return false;'; return false;"
```

Comment: How do I add that in with JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="image" src="/images/check.png" alt="Comment!">` instead. This will act as a submit button, with the added advantage of not requiring JavaScript. There's no good reason to use JavaScript to replicate things that HTML can already do perfectly well.

Comment: But I am calling a function not just submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

removing the onclick handler sounds like the right answer, if you need more information on what and how please go to http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a "Submitting..." image and change the code like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.onclick = "return false;"; this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src="/images/submitting.png"; submitComment('+[id]+'); return false;">
    <img class="submitcommentimg" id="submitcommentimg<?php echo $id; ?>" src="/images/check.png" alt="Comment!" border="0">
</a>
```

...or something like that.

In this example the image is called "submitting.png".

Comment: So it changes its own code? Wouldn't I want to call my function first then change it?

Comment: It clears it's own onclick attribute so that nothing happens the second time the visitor clicks on it. Switching to a different image that says something like "Submitting..." lets the user know that his input has been accepted and is being processed.